# Can we hide column inside the main tree view based on condition of odoo

Tags: tree, odoo, treeview, field, hide

I've been customizing inventory module in odoo 16, there we have multiple operation types for that each individual operation types i have different fields in form fields , so i wanted same in the (main tree) tree view but i was not able make the column invisible based on the condition

eg 1:
<field name="project_name" attrs="{'column_invisible': [('picking_type_code', '!=', 'incoming')]}'/>

ex 2:
<field name='project_name" invisible="context.get('projet_name',False)"/>

ex 3:
<field name="project_name" attrs="{'invisible': [('project_name', '=', False)]

ex  4:
<field name="project_name" invisible=context.get('picking_type_code')!='incoming'"/>

theses are all code tries i've tried , if you have any different kind of idea..Please Share

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use the following syntax:

   ```
    invisible="context.get('quotation_only', False)"
   ```

   You can find an example in the purchase module. The value is passed through the [action context](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/16.0/addons/purchase/views/purchase_views.xml#L659)

   The value of invisible is an expression that will be evaluated in the current context, you can use the following syntax:

   ```
   context.get('picking_type_code') != 'incoming'
   ```
2. You can also use the `invisible` attribute:

   ```
    attrs="{'invisible': ['|', '|', ('state', '=', 'purchase'), ('state', '=', 'done'), ('state', '=', 'cancel')]}"
   ```

In the first example, Odoo hides the column, in the second example, the field's visibility depends on the value of another field, which hides the field in the corresponding row.

For `column_invisible` attribute, you can read the following note in the [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/developer/reference/backend/views.html?highlight=column_invisible#list):

> In case of list sub-views (One2many/Many2many display in a form view), The attribute column_invisible can be useful to hide a column depending on the parent object.